# uwsgi cache expire setting

Tags: caching, uwsgi

hi I'm new to uwsgi and I'm not english speaker, sorry for my english

I'm hoping that uwsgi's cache doesn't expire until uwsgi terminates, but I'm not sure my code is right.

Below is my code

`uwsgi.ini`

```
cache2 = name=store,itmes=10,blocksize=124
```

`test.py`

```
import uwsgi

uwsgi.cache_update('test','foo',0,'store')
```

I already check the uwsgi doc
(https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Caching.html)

but I can't clearly understand below mean..

`The expires argument (default to 0 for disabled) is the number of seconds after the object is no more valid (and will be removed by the cache sweeper when purge_lru is not set, see below)`

If I do this, it won't expire, right? Or should I use another method?